# How to remove a view and update constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view in which i am creating another view programmatically on add button through xib. I am able to create multiple views on tapping add more button and remove is also working if I remove last view but the problem occurs with middle views due to missing constraints view not updating correctly bellow are images how it is looking

**At start view Look like this**

[image]

**After Adding more view**

[image]

**After removing middle view**

[image]

Delete button code

```
@IBAction func deletebnt(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let view = self.superview
        let index =  view?.subviews.index(of:self)!
        delegate.txtcheck(text: countstr)
         self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Add button Code

```
@IBAction func addMoreBnt(_ sender: UIButton) {
      for constraint in addSuperview.constraints {
            if constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height
            {
                constraint.constant +=  45
                space = constraint.constant
            }
        }
        let newView : AvalabileTimeView = AvalabileTimeView()
        newView.frame = CGRect(x: self.addsubView.frame.origin.x, y: 70, width: addsubView.frame.size.width, height:addsubView.frame.size.height)
        newView.delegate = self as AvalabileTimeDelegate
        addSuperview.addSubview(newView)
        let index = addSuperview.subviews.index(of: newView)!        
        newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let heightConstraint = newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:addsubView.frame.size.width )
        let widthConstaint = newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:31 )
        let topConstraint = newView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addSuperview.topAnchor, constant: space - 31)  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([heightConstraint,topConstraint,widthConstaint])

    }
```

delegate to change height of superview

```
func txtcheck(text: String!) {
        print(text)
        for constraint in addSuperview.constraints {
            if constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.height
            {
                constraint.constant -=  45
                // Here I have to set constraint for bottom view and topview of deleted view but I don't know how to do
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is link to demo project 
https://github.com/logictrix/addFieldDemo

Comment: Use UITabelView. You can achieve This Type of Action very easily.

Comment: @Ujesh Yes I have to use other option if I failed to fix this, right now I am trying to fix this.

Comment: This can be of course fixed, but it's better to use a TableView, It is understandable if this is an assignment where you are unable to use TableViews. Otherwise always use the best tools Apple provides you for the job.

Comment: @CoderFrom94 This not assignment but if I use tableview I have to design & code for the whole ViewController from start that I don't want to do if I can quick fix this with some help

Comment: TableView might have been a good idea for the *full* interface, but trying to add a TableView for just that section would be really tough to make work (vertical scrolling table view inside a vertical scrolling scroll view).

Comment: @VarunNaharia Add code : self.view.layoutIfNeeded() in deleteButton Method as last line of that method. Also instead of using UIView  && addd it every time , tableview is better option. please try this using tableview you problem will solve...!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding each new `AvalabileTimeView` with its own constraints, use a `UIStackView` - you can remove almost all of your existing code for adding / removing the new views.

Look at `.addArrangedSubview()` and `.removeArrangedSubview()`

Here is some sample code... you'll need to add a UIStackView in Interface Builder, connect it to the Outlet, and adjust the constraints, but that's about all:

```
// in ViewController.swift

@IBOutlet weak var availableTimeStackView: UIStackView!

@IBAction func addMoreBnt(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // instantiate a new AvalabileTimeView
    let newView : AvalabileTimeView = AvalabileTimeView()

    // set its delegate to self
    newView.delegate = self as AvalabileTimeDelegate

    // add it to the Stack View
    availableTimeStackView.addArrangedSubview(newView)

    // standard for auto-layout
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // only constraint needed is Height (width and vertical spacing handled by the Stack View)
    newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 31).isActive = true

}

// new delegate func
func removeMe(_ view: AvalabileTimeView) {

    // remove the AvalabileTimeView from the Stack View
    availableTimeStackView.removeArrangedSubview(view)

}
```

---

```
// in AvalabileTimeView.swift

protocol AvalabileTimeDelegate{
    // don't need this anymore
    func txtcheck(text: String!)

    // new delegate func
    func removeMe(_ view: AvalabileTimeView)
}

@IBAction func deletebnt(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate.removeMe(self)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for remembering me about stack view I totally forgot about that It might solve my problem I'll check and let you about that